# Flutter webrtc video calling issue:Not stopping "I/org.webrtc.Logging(32282): EglRenderer: Duration.." after hangup the call

Tags: flutter, webrtc

[image]
I tried to find the solution. But I failed. Please help me if anybody know the solution.

Comment: a solution for what? please explani better your problem, maybe before read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue.
just these lines:

```
 _localRenderer.dispose();
```

_remoteRenderer.dispose();

Comment: when using _localRenderer.dispose(); or _remoteRenderer.dispose();
I received the following error

'A $runtimeType was used after being disposed.\n'
'Once you have called dispose() on a $runtimeType, it can no longer be used.'
What exactly is wrong?

Comment: what is this localRenderer, where is it created from?

Answer (score 1):

You must set the **srcObject** as null also like this code

```
localRenderer.srcObject = null;
await localRenderer.dispose();
```